# How to attach file buffer to Django Mail Queue

Tags: python, django, attachment

I have been trying to attach an xls buffer or a pdf buffer to a Django mail queue, but I couldn't.

I've tried using FileResponse or HttpResponse and converting to a Django file object but that fails, too.

This is what I tried:

```
new_message = MailerMessage()
new_message.subject = "Test"
new_message.to_address = "test@gmail.com"
new_message.from_address = "noreply@gmail.com"

file_attachment = FileResponse('file_content_buffer', content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')

new_message.add_attachment(file_attachment)     

new_message.save()
```

I got an error:
`'FileResponse' object has no attribute 'file'`.
I know that the attachment method waits for a File Object as the documentation says:
https://django-mail-queue.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#attaching-files.

Any idea? Thanks.

**Solution:**
Little hacky watching what mailqueue code does. What do you think?

```
from mailqueue.models import MailerMessage, Attachment

new_message = MailerMessage()
new_message.subject = "Subject Mail"
new_message.to_address = 'test@gmail.com'
new_message.from_address = 'noreply@gmail.com'

new_message.save()

attachment = Attachment()
attachment.file_attachment.save('file.xlsx',ContentFile(excel_buffer),save=False)
attachment.email = new_message
attachment.original_filename = 'file.xlsx'
try:
    new_attachment.save()
except Exception as e:
    new_attachment.file_attachment.delete()
```

Comment: Shouldn't **file_content_buffer** be **file_content_buffer.xls** ?

Comment: @LearningNoob, file_content_buffer is only as sample. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this **Django version 2.1**:

`file_attachment = FileResponse(open('myfile.xls', 'rb'),as_attachment=True,'myfile.xls')`

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/) is the official django documentation on how to use FileResponse.

Adding an answer for **Django 1.9**, using `HTTPResponse`:

```
file_attachment = HttpResponse('myfile.xls', content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel') 
file_attachment['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="myfile.xls"'
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment)

Comment: @LearningNoob, my app is with django 1.9. I replaced the open('myfile.xls') with my buffer but the 'as_attachment' didnt like. I think because the version.

Comment: @hanskait, I have added an alternative for Django 1.9

Comment: @LearningNoob, i got this error with alternative code:File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/........./lib/python3.4/site-packages/mailqueue/models.py", line 73, in add_attachment
    original_filename = attachment.file.name.split(os.sep)[-1]
AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'file'

Comment: @hanskait what buffer or file are you passing?

Comment: @LearningNoob for example the result of save_virtual_workbook -> from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

Comment: @LearningNoob from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title = 'Title'

excel_buffer = save_virtual_workbook(wb)

Comment: @LearningNoob, i posted a possible solution. Tell me what you think.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use FileResponse to attach a buffer. Suppose you have a BytesIO object buffer, you just need to convert it to a bytes-like object:

```
content = buffer.read()

EmailMessage.attach('File Name.xls', content)
EmailMessage.send()
```